# JavaFX Assigning action to all buttons in an array of arrays using for-loop

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, local-variables, actionevent

We have this warm up exercise where we're supposed to create this reallllly simple game which's UI is pretty much set up

[image: which's UI is pretty much set up].

I got the error **"Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final".**

I didn't understand it, so I googled it, but most of the problems are different.
While typing this question I found this in the stackoverflow suggestions:

[Assigning an action to each button, in an array of buttons in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323804/assigning-an-action-to-each-button-in-an-array-of-buttons-in-javafx)

But I simply don't understand. I'm learning programming/java from scratch. I hope JavaFX/GuI stuff isn't a hindrance?

The code below only includes my attempt to assign the actions. I separated it from the creation of the buttons for the time being to figure out what the problem is. The problem is only in the if and else conditions.

```
    for(int i=0; i<=4; i++) {

        for(int j=0; j<=4; j++) {

            buttonGrid[i][j].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    
                    if (buttonGrid[i][j].getText() == "X") {
                        buttonGrid[i][j].setText("O");
                    } else {
                        buttonGrid[i][j].setText("X");
                    }
                }
            });
         }
    }
```

For now I just want the button's labels to change from X to O and from O to X as you click them. Btw. If I learn JavaFX and GUI, does it mean I HAVE to learn css? (Not that I don't want to, just.. not now)

If there is a need for the rest of the code to figure the problem:
http://textuploader.com/5b1kh

I'd also appreciate if someone could tell me how to do the Scenes in a more efficent way. (Btw, can I somehow lock the aspect ratio of the sides of all cells of a gridpane?)

Comment: The error is because variables are copied inside an anonymous class and so has to be final. Better explanation here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the answer in this question explains your problem very well and how to solve it [Problems with local variable scope. How to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894509/problems-with-local-variable-scope-how-to-solve-it) You can not use i and j inside the Action handler.

Try this. [Notice that I've also changed the string comparison*]

```
 for(int i=0; i<=4; i++) {

    for(int j=0; j<=4; j++) {

        final Button myButton = buttonGrid[i][j];

        myButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                if ("X".equals(myButton.getText())) {
                    myButton.setText("O");
                } else {
                    myButton.setText("X");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[*] [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it to work, but I used Button, idk what JButton is and I kept my String comparison, because yours for some reason gave me a Syntax error, although there should be none..

edit: nvm there was just a bracket missing

Comment: @HenryLa You're welcome. JButton is a Swing class. More or less the previous version of JavaFx. My mistake. Mark the answer as accepted if it has been useful, please.